# Is it possible to skip over annotation validation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I have User entity whose username field is annotated by `@UniqueUsername` validation. When receiving request in controller, I use `@Valid` annotation for validation. This works perfectly when I'm creating users. But, I'm having issues with editing existing users, because I can't make spring to ignore `@UniqueUsername`, so every edit fails. Is there some way to make spring to ignore `@UniqueUsername` when editing/updating user info?

This is my simplified code:

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    //my custom validator
    @UniqueUsername
    private String username;
    public int getId() {
    return id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**UniqueUsername**

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueUsername {
    String message() default "Username already exists";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**UniqueUsernameValidator**

```
@Component
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername username) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !userDetailsService.isUsernameAlreadyInUse(username);
    }
}
```

Method in my controller looks like this:

```
public String updateUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model)
```

Comment: how about taking into account `id` in your `isUsernameAlreadyInUse(username)` also; like passing the id also and making checks whether this is an update or an insert?

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass an ID through annotation because these annotations require static values only. For example i could do @UniqueUsername(id = 5), but i can't do: @UniqueUsername(id = this.id)

Comment: I added an answer; please check it. You should not pass the `id` to the annotation; you can take the path variable id from within the validator class!

Comment: Why you want to change the required behavior of the application `unique user` ? if you change this behavior on [edit] operation it means there can be data redundancy or two users can or will have same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get whether the path variable `id` within `UniqueUsernameValidator`, you can do the following:

```
@Component
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername username) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Map<String, String> uriVars = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

        if (uriVars != null) {
          String idStr = uriVars.get("id");

          if (idStr != null) {
            int id = Integer.valueOf(ValidationUtils.getPathVariable(request, "id"));

            return !userDetailsService.isUserNameAlreadyInUseForAnotherId(userName, id);
          }
        }

        return !userDetailsService.isUsernameAlreadyInUse(username);
    }
}
```

You can get the path variable from the injected `HttpServletRequest` and implement a new service method `isUserNameAlreadyInUseForAnotherId` and perform checks specifically for update case. Hope this helps!

Comment: @bici good to hear; may be you can mark as accepted answer as well; if it solves your problem.